# "dmesg" not working with Linux Kernel module spanning over multiple files

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Hi all Stackoverflow users.

I am a beginner into Linux kernel module programming. I have written a simple kernel module having two source files and two header files and the module builds successfully.The files are as follows.

```
Filename:**kernel_module.c**

#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include"kmod_opr.h"

static _int32_t __init _mod_init(void);
static void __exit _mod_exit(void);
static _int32_t __init _mod_init(void)
{
    pr_info("MODULE-123 inserted in kernel.\n");
    call_from_init();
    return 0;
}
static void __exit _mod_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("MODULE-123 removed from kernel.\n");
    call_from_exit();
}
module_init(_mod_init);
module_exit(_mod_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("AUTHOR NAME");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("MODULE-1");


 Filename:**kmod_opr.c**

#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include"types.h"
void call_from_init(void)
{
    pr_info("call_from_init() called.\n");
}
void call_from_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("call_from_exit() called.\n");
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


Filename:**kmod_opr.h**
#ifndef __KMOD_OPR_H__
#define __KMOD_OPR_H__
#include"types.h"
extern void call_from_init(void);
extern void call_from_exit(void);
#endif

 Filename:**types.h**
#ifndef __TYPES_H__
#define __TYPES_H__
typedef unsigned int        _uint32_t;
typedef signed int          _int32_t;
typedef short unsigned int  _uint16_t;
typedef short signed int    _int16_t;
typedef unsigned char       _uint8_t;
typedef char                _int8_t;
#endif
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += kernel_module.o
kernel_module-objs += kmod_opr.o

KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The module successfully loads into kernel but "dmesg" does not show the pr_info messages from my module.
Not sure whether the init function is getting called on insmod or not.
But if the supported source file(kmod_opr.c/kmod_opr.h) are removed and the module is built without the supported files then the dmesg shows the pr_info messages from the module on insmod.

Not sure what is going wrong.
Any help on this issue will be much appreciated.

New Makefile:

```
obj-m += final_build.o
final_build-objs += kernel_module.o kmod_opr.o

KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Thanks

Comment: `typedef signed int          _int32_t;` why the `types.h`? There is already `int32_t` in `stdint.h`, no? And I think, in kernel `s32` and `u32` types are still preferred. Could you share your makefile?

Comment: @KamilCuk. I have attached the Makefile i am using.

Comment: What is your logging level set to?

Comment: I am able to solve the issue. I made some modifications to my Makefile and now the issue is resolved.

Comment: My build process was wrong. I edited the make file and got the code working. I have updated the makefile in description.